# How to upload audio(wav) file to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

**UPDATED SOLUTION BELOW**

---

After searching around and i found out some demo codes from the google quickstart demo and it worked really well for image 
https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart


Now i want to head further by trying to upload a wav file up to the google drive. 
I have some basic knowledge on Android coding so i try my best to figure out myself until i got stuck. 


Here's my codes.

First i show a list of WAV files in the user's phone

```
for(File singleFile : files){
        if(singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()){
            al.addAll(Songs(singleFile));

        }
        else{
            if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".WAV")){
                al.add(singleFile);
            }
        }
    }
```

next i try to get the user to select the wav file they want to upload

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.songs,R.id.song,items);
        listView.setAdapter(adp);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(bytes==null) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class).putExtra("pos", position).putExtra("songlist", Songs));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

after that i try to use this to get the position and the data of the song selected.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    Songs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");
    position = b.getInt("pos",0);
    u = Uri.parse(Songs.get(position).toString());
```

This is where i'm stuck, i'm not sure if i'm in the right direction to successfully upload a wav file up to the drive.
**Disclaimer, all my codes are adapted from my past codes which shows a list of wav file and select it to play.**
so i may be wrong from the start but i need some guidance for what i should do next, im not sure about converting the file to bytes/string and store in outputstream.

i really hope someone will guide me as I've been searching for the past two weeks about this.

**Thank you.**

---

**UPDATE **

Hello guys, i've found another way to upload to google drive. And i would like to share with everyone. This is a continuation of my codes from above.
Here's the code.

First you get the name of the wav file you want to select.

```
final String name = Songs.get(position).getName();
```

Then you put it in this few lines of codes.

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name));
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri );
            share.setType("audio/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

This part let you share with all the apps that allow you to share wav/audio files and Google Drive is one of them.

Hope this works for you too. Enjoy